# Spring boot + apache CXF Soap client

Tags: spring-boot, soap, wsdl, cxf

can any one help me to get an up to date and complete tuto for Spring boot with apach CXF in order to consume an existing wsdl file?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use [cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/springboot.html#SpringBoot-SpringBootCXFJAX-WSStarter) along with [WSDL2Java Tooling](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/tools.html).

You can adapt the existing sample from GitHub: https://github.com/apache/cxf/tree/master/distribution/src/main/release/samples/jaxws_spring_boot

This one is code first, but you'll find WSDL first examples too that you can adapt for your usecase.